# Django Queryset's annotate returns only a single result

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model called `Schedule` which has a ManyToManyField, `roomId`. This links to the `Room` model, which has an important `ForeignKey`, `buildingId`.

For my QuerySet, I need the list of `buildingId`s for each `roomId`.

What I've tried:

```
queryset = Schedule.objects.all().annotate(buildingId=F('roomId__buildingId'))
```

And also:

```
queryset = Schedule.objects.all().annotate(buildingId=RawSQL("select roomId from api_room where buildingId_id = 1", ()))
```

The second one is just a test which should return two results.
Both of these only return the first result. So the `buildingId` I get is the ID of the first result, instead of a list of all matching results.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as you're expecting, it will return only one `buildingId` for every `Schedule` object. Database can't return data in tree format which will be required here.

What you can do is to access each building from `Schedule` objects using:

```
queryset = Schedule.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('roomId', queryset=Room.objects.all().select_related('buildingId'))

for schedule in queryset:
    rooms = schedule.roomId.objects.all()
    for room in rooms:
        building = room.buildingId
```

That will execute only 2 queries on your database.

Comment: This seems fine, but how can I add the `building` property on the `queryset`? It should be working with my `filter_class` and `serializer_class` too.